# Is there a better software/library towards analytics (and visualisation)?

Tags: data-visualization, data-analysis

I've got product data (`time, title, price, likes, colour, etc.`) from several shops and I would like to do some analysis on it. Some are quite easy:

- Total amount of products per shop
- Pie Chart of colour distribution per country
- Amount of likes over time (line chart)
- Price changes

What I'm currently using is **Python** + **Pandas** for most of the transformation/data manipulation etc. From there I convert DataFrames into dicts and dump them as JSON files. Those are being loaded via **Chart.js**.

That is working ok but it takes me hours, if not days for every new idea of what kind of analisys I'd like to do or which answer I'd like to visualise.

Then I read about TensorFlow and it all sounds so awesome - maybe that would be a way to go to analyse trends or get more knowledge out of my data?

Or would a traditional BI do a sufficient job here?

Maybe just JasperSoft to visualise the data?

I don't have a specific question/analytics requirement - it's more like a hobby project which is growing over time.

Comment: The non-graphical analyses you listed sound like they would be straightforward in Pandas. For graphics, why not use Matplotlib?

Comment: Matplotlib just looks so oldschool compared to Chart.js, even when using mpld3. But I just found that [plotly seems to be able to create nice dashboards](https://plot.ly/python/dashboard/)

Comment: Matplotlib is capable of lots of appearances other than the default. See for example [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/), which achieves a close imitation of ggplot2's style just by changing Matplotlib options.

Comment: Will this always be desktop, or would you ever want to put in on an interactive, auto-updating, web site, to share with others?

Comment: Do you have an operating system in mind? A budget? If you want it free, please add the [tag:gratis] tag, for a specific operating system, please add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention where these data are stored, so I guess it's on a database.

If you are looking for something Open Source, Free and on-premises have a look at [Metabase](http://Metabase.com).

It takes really just 5 minutes, if not under to get your first graph on the screen. Currently, it supports the following databases:

- MySQL
- Postgres
- Mongo
- SQL Server
- AWS Redshift
- Google BigQuery
- Druid
- H2
- SQLite
- Oracle
- Crate
- Google Analytics
- Vertica

I've used it visualize data from our Service Desk software that is based on MySQL.

[image]

Comment: Please focus on the question, and detail how the software would solve each of the asker's requirements.

Comment: A great recommendation, though :-)

Comment: I tried plenty of solutions and stuck with this one here. Very easy to install, fast to get to a visualisation. Now if I want to get to some very specific info / analysis, I'd need to add a field or table or similar and fill it with Python / Panda or directly through PHP where our data comes from. But the rest is good. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Tableu. It is an excellent package especially for displaying data and building histograms. It is totally point and click except for defining certain equations or number of bins for a histogram. This app is great for data exploration and finding trends. I became aware of it via a data science tutorial. The package is not cheap even for a single user license but you have 2 other options. There is a 14 day free trail period so you can determine if you like it and there is a free version but you can only save your data on their server. Hence not a good option for proprietary data but fine as a hobby project. The free version is available at tableu.public site. I'd suggest looking at a brief Tableu tutorial to learn its many capabilities.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I'm a big fan of open source software and especially for a hobby project I'd not like my data in someone elses company/server and learn/do sth. by myself. I heard from Tableu before but the pricing is just a no go for hobby/small businesses - as good as the whole thing might be. :(

Comment: Agreed but free version is full featured.

Answer (score 2):

[Syncfusion Dashboard](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/dashboard) is an end to end Dashboard solution. The Dashboard Designer can be used for data analysis and visualization.

The dashboard can be deployed with the dashboard server or embedded in your application.

[image: Syncfusion Dashboard]

Syncfusion Dashboard platform is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) for hobby and small business(less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 2):

**[Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/e)**  I just recently learned of this application and it may be just what you need. It's free and open source. I haven't used it myself but the description sounds similar to Tableu (without the cost). Their web page states "Web-based notebook that enables data-driven, interactive data analytics". You can learn more at the Apache Zeppelin web site. Only downside is maybe learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the open source BI product http://www.helicalinsight.com 
You can drag drop and create report, select any of the visualizations, customize the look and feel, add filters, add database functions, export it, share it, save it, use them in dashboard as well.
It comes with free version as well as enterprise version.
You will be able to see a list of various database icons, you can also add your own db drivers, add your own charts, add your own customnizations, use the API and extend functionalities etc.