# Non-Windows-based BI software that can be easily connected to MongoDB

Tags: data-analysis, performance-analysis, business-intelligence, mongodb

I have a website that is built on MongoDB. I am tracking its KPIs: visitors, visits. I want to analyze these data in real time by a BI software. So I am looking for a BI software:

1. can be easily connected to MongoDB
2. can be used in Mac or in a web browser (because I don't have
   Windows)
3. not very expensive (at the moment, I have not too many data
   and don't need too fanny analytics)

I have done some research, it seems that

- `Qlik Sense` does not have Mac Desktop; `Qlik Sense Clould` cannot connect to MongoDB.
- `Microsoft Power BI` is only Windows-based.
- `Tableau` has a Mac Desktop that can be connected to MongoDB, but the price is 70 dollars/month.

Am I missing something? Could anyone help?

Comment: See also [this related question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/43294/is-there-a-better-software-library-towards-analytics-and-visualisation)

Answer (score 0):

Well it sounds like [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/download) meets your requirement. It is not very expensive and quite adaptive to many data sources, including [MongoDb](http://www.pentaho.com/analytics-for-mongodb).

Pentaho doesn't only provides reporting solution but also offers ETL & OLAP (Mondarian) along with it. It comes up with 30 days trial but you can ofcourse have a look into it before downloading . Click [here](http://demo.pentaho.com/pentaho/Home?locale=en_US) for the demo (you might need to be asked to provide few details before accessing demo)

***Disclaimer**: I don't work for Pentaho  or its related entity. recommendation is purely based upon my experience & knowledge of data warehousing over a decade.*

Comment: Pentaho has community edition for free.